# AngularJS : only one line shows up, not the other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

AngularJS : only one line shows up, not the other

I have AngularJS code and only one of them shows up in my page

```
function Today($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.now_time = 0;

  (function update() {
    $timeout(update, 1000);
    var now = moment();
    $scope.now_time = now.format("ddd, MMM Do, h:mm:ss a");
  }());
}


function Yesterday($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.yst_date = 0;

  (function update() {
    $timeout(update, 1000);
    var yst = moment().subtract('days', 1);
    $scope.yst_date = yst.format("ddd, MMM Do");
  }());
}
```

And in the html, I have:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Today">{{now_time}}</div>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Yesterday">{{yst_date}}</div>
```

And only the first `now_time` shows up.

How should I set up the variables or anything else to show both?

Comment: You should only have one `ng-app`. Put it on your `html` tag and try again...

Comment: Pretty sure you can only have one ng-app per application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put both in the same app:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Today">{{now_time}}</div>
  <div ng-controller="Yesterday">{{yst_date}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I want to diplay them in different lines?

Comment: Divs are block elements so they will be on different lines.